# Install Method of Installer Class not getting fired while Updating the installer-Install Shield Limited Edition

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield-le

We are working on a  WPF application and we used  Install Shield Limited Edition to create  the installer of the application.  As per requirement we need to encrypt the App.config file. So we used an installer class and  encrypted the  app.config using “DataProtectionConfigurationProvider”. We have written the corresponding code to “Install” method of Installer Class.  To associate the installer class to Install Shields we used following way.

[image]

Later we have build the application and we are able to successfully create the installer. We also found the the App.config section is encrypted correctly.

Now the issue is “Install” method of “Installer” class not getting fired when we update to new version of the same product.  First our version was 1.0.1.0 and later we added  some feature to the application and created new version 1.0.1.1 . At that time we notice that the “Install” method of “Installer” class not getting fired.

How we solve this issue? I am stuck with this issue. Any help would be appreciable.

Best Regards

Ranish